# Salesforce App for Outlook Documentation

Tags: salesforce-for-outlook

As Salesforce and Microsoft just announced the new Salesforce App for Outlook just a mere 6 days ago I installed it for our organization. Being so new and in Beta, I can't find a lot of information about it.  We are using Outlook 2013 but It seems to fail to provide the information in the dropdown.  When I open up the email in a web browser, It works as expected.  Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I have installed it in a test org/environment and have found that it is very limited in functionality and the user experience is lacking. Its only use right now is a quick view of related records to that contact. I cannot seem to get the Outlook 2013 app loaded. Probably something I'm doing but not impressed so far.

This article is of course slanted to Cirrus's product but still a good quick read: http://www.cirrusinsight.com/blog/the-pros-and-cons-of-the-salesforce-app-for-outlook/